# How to read pickled files using command line in Python?

Tags: python, function, command-line, pickle

I have 2 pickled files on the computer and I want to load it to my script. Would this code I wrote work in python?

```
import sys
import pickle
filename1 = sys.argv(1)
filename2 = sys.argv(2)
       
def read_file(filename1,filename2):   
            
  with open(filename1, 'rb') as file1:         
    file1=pickle.load()
      
  with open(filename1, 'rb') as file2:         
    file2=pickle.load()

return file1
return file2

sys.exit()
```

Comment: There are multiple issues with the code: 1. you cannot use two `return`s, but you can return two values; 2. typo in the 2nd `open()`, I assume you want to open `filename2`; 3. you perhaps want to refer to [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) library page for the usage of `load()` function. You can also save your code and run it to learn from the Error messages.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle):

```
   1 # Load the dictionary back from the pickle file.
   2 import pickle
   3 
   4 favorite_color = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
   5 # favorite_color is now { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }
```

So in your case you can do:

```
def read_file(filename1,filename2):   
            
  with open(filename1, 'rb') as file1:         
    f1=pickle.load(file1)
      
  with open(filename1, 'rb') as file2:         
     f2=pickle.load(file2)

  return f1,f2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that don't quite work here:

- Your second `with`-clause is not inside of your function, neither are your returns
- A function can only return once. When python reaches the first return inside a function, it exits that function. But you can return multiple things at once, e.g. with `return file1, file2`
- Your pickle-loading is the other way around. Like this, you redefine your `file1` and `file2` - variables with whatever your call of `pickle.load()` (notice that it didn't get any arguments) would give you -- what you want is to pass the file you opened to `pickle.load` and then save the output of that to a new variable
- You never actually called your `read_file` function
- your indentation seems to be off
- `sys.argv` is a list, you can't call it (Round braces, like `sys.argv(1)`) but you can index it (square brackets `sys.argv[1]`)

```py
import sys
import pickle
       
def read_file(filename1,filename2):   
            
    with open(filename1, 'rb') as file1:         
        data1 = pickle.load(file1)
      
    with open(filename1, 'rb') as file2:         
        data2 = pickle.load(file2)
    
    return data1, data2


filename1 = sys.argv[1]
filename2 = sys.argv[2]
your_data = read_file(filename1, filename2)
print(your_data)  # Now you use your data, i used print as an example
sys.exit()  # You usually only write that if you specifically need to
```

Further suggestion:

You don't necessarily have to make one function to handle two files, you can also just make one function to handle one file and call it twice.

```py
import pickle


def read_file(filename):   
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file1: 
        data = pickle.load(file1)
    return data1


filename1 = sys.argv[1]
filename2 = sys.argv[2]

your_data = read_file(filename1), read_file(filename2)
print(your_data)
```